# Partial string match in jsonb using Hasura graphql API?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I'm trying to do the following query:

```
query Feeds($id: Int!) {
  feed_by_pk(id: $id) {
    feed_items(where: {contents: {_contains: {blocks: [{text: "%test%"}]}}}) {
      id
      contents
      created_at
      created_by
      last_edited
      user {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where I'd like to match the value 'text' against 'test' but ignoring case (so Test, tESt, etc will hit) and also partial matching (i.e. "this is a Test" will work).

I've tried using %test% to no avail, is there a specific way to do this for JSONBs with Hasura?

Comment: From my impressions "hasura way" is "write a postgresql function when something needed". I would write a function that returns `feed_items` filtered by ILIKE  and pass '%test%`  in `args` instead of `where`